# Backup folder full

Tags: vps, database

my clients server (CentOS) with a disk space of 20gb is almost full.

Client uses WHM/cpanel and backups set for weekly

Seems like the /backup has the  most in it.

How do i delete files in this folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, check with your client that this is okay. Double-check that there is nothing important in here and that you can afford to lose this data, then, log into the server with SSH, go into the `/backup` folder and us the `rm` command to delete whatever files are in there. The following remove commands are destructive and it's difficult to recover files once they've been deleted:

1. You can move to the directory with `cd /backup`
2. You can check for what files are in the folder with `ls /backup`
3. You can remove files in the folder by using `rm /backup/filename` where you replace filename with the appropriate file name.
4. You can remove the contents of the entire folder using `rm -rf /backup/*`

Comment: Hey. This is a huge help. Thanks. How do i delete files in this folder older that 7 days for example?

Comment: No problem. A simple way would be to check the date and timestamps on the files using `ls -l /backup` and then remove the specific files using number 3.

Comment: mate you are a legend thank you so much! its worked! :)

Comment: @rohan groombrodge No problem. If you feel my answer is sufficient, please mark it correct.